# php code not indenting in adobe brackets

Tags: php, html, adobe-brackets, code-editor

I am using [Adobe Brackets 1.0](http://brackets.io/) code editor.

I have `.php` pages that include `HTML` & `PHP` lines.

`HTML` lines indenting fine **BUT** `PHP` lines do not indent correctly!

is there any extension or way to force `PHP` lines to indent correctly?

I've used and tried the following extensions but non of them did the job:

1. [[PHP-SIG] PHP SmartHints](https://github.com/mackenza/Brackets-PHP-SmartHints)
2. [PHP Syntax Hint](http://www.oslibrary.in/brackets/)
3. [QuickDocsPHP](https://github.com/Wikunia/brackets-QuickDocsPHP)
4. [QuickDocsRegEx](https://github.com/Wikunia/brackets-QuickDocsRegEx)
5. [Tab tags](https://github.com/bryanjhv/brackets-tab-tags)
6. [WordHint](https://github.com/bigeyex/brackets-wordhint)

Thanks

*P.S. I can't believe such good editor lack this important feature & functionality out-of-the-box.*

---

**UPDATE** after *Nicolò's* answer:

1. Before using "Indentator" extension (Manual indentation)

[image]

2. After installing "Indentator" extension and applying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

Comment: why the down-voting?!!! what is wrong with the question? every one is free to down vote any question if he/she think it is off-topic or badly submitted or *for any other reason* **BUT** be helpful and brave by explaining why you down vote it so we can avoid the mistakes in the future!!!!!!!

Comment: Don't get mad, there are people up voting as well. I up voted too, because I have the same question about indenting PHP in brackets. By the way, I think the Indentator's result is reasonable because the PHP code has its own scope and it should be different from HTML in terms of large chunk of PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to indent `php` codes

all what I had to do is to wrap the `php` code inside `{}`

**Example**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <!-- some html contents -->
      <?php
      {
        //your php code here;
        //next lines will be indented correctly;
      }
      ?>
      <div>
        <div>
          <?php
          {
            //php code here;
            //another php line;
          }
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I found this way works fine with me and not causing any issues to the codes or to the pages.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the "Indentator" extension and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

**UPDATE** After SULTAN's update:

There is an issue on GitHub about this problem:
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10038

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.  I'll update the question with two images showing the results.